# JSON pretty printing: how to output Buffer objects in hex format

Tags: node.js, json, hex

I am trying to print an object that contains multiple Buffer instances (the example is limited to one):

```
const buf = new Buffer.from("abcdefgh");
console.log(JSON.stringify({a:1,b:2,c:{d:1,e:buf}}, null, 4));
```

Whenever I convert such an object to JSON the output is undesired log and the buffer in decimal instead of hexadecimal (e.g. as hex string):

```
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": {
        "d": 1,
        "e": {
            "type": "Buffer",
            "data": [
                97,
                98,
                99,
                100,
                101,
                102,
                103,
                104
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**How can I pretty print arbitrary JavaScript objects in Node.js in a way that all Buffer instances are printed as nice hex string as hex like this?**

```
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": {
        "d": 1,
        "e": "6162636465666768"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add the buffer to the JSON you should add the string instead of the buffer.

```
const buf = new Buffer.from('abcdefgh')
const myJson = JSON.stringify({ a: 1, b: 2, c: { d: 1, e: buf.toString('hex') } }, null, 4)
console.log(myJson)
```

**UPDATED**
Because you are just receiving the data you need to check if any value is a buffer and if it is cast it into a hex string. I created a recursive function to check if any of the values is an object, if it is I recursively call the function. If the value is a buffer I cast to hex string.

```
const buf = new Buffer.from('abcdefgh')
const stringJson = JSON.stringify({ a: 1, b: 2, c: { d: 1, e: buf } }, null, 4)
const parsedJson = JSON.parse(stringJson)
myRecursiveFunction(parsedJson)
console.log(parsedJson)

function myRecursiveFunction (obj) {
  for (const key in obj) {
    if (isObject(obj[key]) && !isBuffer(obj[key])) {
      myRecursiveFunction(obj[key])
    } else if (isBuffer(obj[key])) {
      obj[key] = Buffer.from(obj[key].data).toString('hex')
    }
  }
}

function isBuffer (obj) {
  return obj && obj.type && obj.type === 'Buffer'
}

function isObject (obj) {
  return typeof obj === 'object' && !Array.isArray(obj) && obj !== null
}
```

Comment: I don't add the Buffer. I am getting ready-to use objects I want to print as Jon string. The code shown in my question is just an example how such an object can look alike.

Comment: I have updated to fulfill your requirements.